# Where can I find a copy of Erlang/OTP R14B05?

Tags: version-control, erlang

I'm trying to find the source for R14B05.

The reason is that I want to see how [Precise Explanation of Typing Errors](https://www.it.uu.se/research/group/hipe/dialyzer) was implemented. That page provides a link to the source code, but it doens't seem to be version-controlled. So I want to diff against the code is based on in order to see what changed.

The page that links to the paper says that the code is based on R14B05, so now I'd like to try diffing against R14B05.

I look at https://github.com/erlang/otp/releases?after=OTP_R16B01_RC1 or `git tag -l` in the repo, I can only find R14B04, then the R15 series–no R14B05.

Comment: Have you checked whether "B05" is a typo and R14B04 is a good enough base for comparison?

Comment: Good point, at least for Dialyzer the entire diff seems relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no R14B05 anywhere, only R14B01-R14B04.

http://erlang.org/download/ and http://erlang.org/documentation/ seems to have old files.

doc-5.8.5 is for Erlang/OTP R14B04, and the next one, which is doc-5.9, is for Erlang/OTP R15B. There does not appear to be a R14B05 one, so perhaps it indeed could be a typo. Perhaps they thought 5.8.5 was R14B05?

You could try contacting the authors as well, just in case.